# 3D camera tracking and object tracking are not on right position

Tags: modeling, objects, camera, tracking, motion-capture

I'm sorry if this question as already been asked, but I couldn't find it anywhere so asking again. If someone knows please write in comments.

The story is, I've a video clip form (hollywoodcameraworks). Very common clip, where a women is holding a gun kind of object and walking on a street.

Please see the images.

I've tracked camera very nicely with 0.01px error. Very smooth camera tracking, this worked great.
[image]

and for object I tracking 0.25px error I don't think that is bad at all,

[image]

And in 3D space ... both things are tracked, 3D box-object has also applied constraints to the tracked OBJECT respected to the camera. that seems fine on the 3D space.

[image]

But the ISSUE is.. the 3D box-box object is too low to the surface... I won't be able to cast shadows since I want to change the road into cracks on concrete or anything in 3D as well... so don't want to do it separately ...   Can somebody give me some tip where I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Thank you.

one more small question: how to add file as attachment.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And after some testing.. I've found the solution..

My camera solution's scale was little.. I had to increase that..

See my first results with solved scale.

1. I selected two points with good results 0.01 and 0.01px,
2. Hit Apply Scale
3. Scale up and keep look on the result preview in right top corner in my image.
   [image]

. this is what I got..

[image]

Perfect. Thank you to ALLAH for giving me solution..  :)